# Precisely how do you delta-hedge a spot-1Y SOFR IRS with SOFR futures?

Tags: interest-rate-swap, delta-hedging, delta, convexity, sofr

I'm struggling to construct hedge ratios that delta-hedge a spot-1Y IRS.

Say I'm roughly in the middle of an IMM period, date = Oct 30th 2023 and I trade a 1k dv01 spot-1Y SOFR swap. I'll need some combination of these SOFR futures to hedge out the delta: [Sep23, Dec23, Mar24, Jun24, Sep24]. Below is an approach I've tried:

Use hedge ratios [1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/8].

My theory being that the middle 3 futures cover full periods of the swap, so I simply take 90/360 of the swap dv01 here.

For the last future, I only need it to cover half of the period as my swap only extends out to half of this period, so I need 45/360 here.

And for the front future, I similarly only need it to cover half the period of the future but here the delta of the future is already halved, since we already have half of the rates from the period. So no adjustment is needed.

I've attempted this running through an IMM to IMM period, systematically multiplying the last 1/4 hedge ratio depending on how far through the IMM period I am but when comparing against swap rates the delta is not hedged. What am I doing wrong?